# How do I add custom script in WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress

I am fairly new to WordPress.

I am currently using a plugin which requires me to **add a custom script before the `</body>` tag.**

How do I do it?

Comment: Before *what* tag?

Comment: Thanks Gavin, I have edited the question. Before the </body> tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options for how to add the required JavaScript. The code below should be added to the `functions.php` file of your WordPress theme (or child theme).

This assumes the WordPress theme has used the [`wp_footer()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_footer/) function correctly.

```
function addScriptTagToBody() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // JavaScript here..
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'addScriptTagToBody' );
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to link to an external JavaScript file, you can use the following:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 
    'custom-script', // A unique name for the script
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom-script.js', // Assumes the script is in your theme directory
    array( 'jquery' ), // An array of dependencies for your script
    '1', // Version number for your script
    true // Add script just before </body> tag
);
```

The fifth argument for [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) lets you specify whether the `<script src=""></script>` is added in the `<head></head>` or just before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: Thank you, Kirk Beard.
Where should I add my code in function.php?

Comment: It shouldn't matter really. Just add it at the end of your `functions.php` file. (`functions.php`, with an s).

Comment: Hi Kirk, I use the first method, this works perfectly, thanks